# Color vertex by deformation value in an animation

Tags: python, animation, vertices, color, bmesh

Hi I have been trying to develop code which shows the amount of deformation on a mesh's edges by coloring the vertices a value which depends on the average change in edge length for the connected vertices. The code currently works but is very slow. Does anyone have a good idea on a way to speed it up?

Here is the code I have so far

```
# Get a BMesh representation
def color_vertex_bm(me): # me is a mesh from me = bpy.context.active_object.data

    bm = bmesh.new()   # create an empty BMesh
    bm.from_mesh(me)   # fill it in from a Mesh
    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

    Ege = get_edges(me)
    sE = (Ege-Ege_0)/Ege_0    # *** Ege_0 is a global variable that stores all initial edge lengths 
    # print(sE)

    # Get first color layer (create if needed)
    if not bm.loops.layers.color:
        bm.loops.layers.color.new('Col')
    layer = bm.loops.layers.color[0]

    for face in bm.faces:

        for loop in face.loops:
            # get vert coord
            current_vert_coord = loop.vert.co
            v = loop.vert
            # get all the edges that belong to this vertex
            Eges = [e.index for e in bm.edges if v in e.verts]
            avg =(np.average(sE[Eges]))
            # custom color map lookup for the average value
            rgba = colormap_jet(avg)
            # assign rgba to the loop
            loop[layer] = rgba
        
    # Finish up, write the bmesh back to the mesh
    bm.to_mesh(me)
    bm.free()  # free and prevent further access

def get_edges(me):

    Ege_local = np.array([])    
    bm = bmesh.new()   # create an empty BMesh
    bm.from_mesh(me)   # fill it in from a Mesh
    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
    
    #get all edge lengths
    for e in bm.edges:
        ege = e.calc_length() 
        Ege_local = np.append(Ege_local, ege)
                
    # Finish up, write the bmesh back to the mesh
    bm.free()  # free and prevent further access

    return Ege_local
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Using `numpy` and `foreach_get`**

In as much as I love using `bmesh`, for speed it is quicker to use `numpy` in conjunction with partners in crime `foreach_get` and `foreach_set` in object mode from the mesh object.

My `numpy` knowledge is rudimentary, so there is a chance that this can be optimised further.

[image]
*Simple Test Run, "Copy" on right of cube on left. Black for no link edge change, red else*

```
import bpy
import numpy as np

class BATVertColors:
    def color_by_verts(self, colors):
        cols = colors[self.vert_index_table]
        self.vcolor_layer.foreach_set(
                "color",
                cols.ravel()
                )
    def __init__(self, me, vcollayer):
        
        nloops = len(me.loops)
        vert_index_table = np.zeros(nloops, dtype=np.int32) 
        me.loops.foreach_get(
                "vertex_index",
                vert_index_table
                )
        self.vcolor_layer = vcollayer
        self.vert_index_table = vert_index_table
        

class BATMesh:
    def vert_link_edges(self, index):
        return np.logical_or(*np.isin(self.edges, index).T)    
    def __init__(self, me, vcol="Col"):
        nverts = len(me.vertices)
        nedges = len(me.edges)
        #nloops = len(me.loops)

        vcoords = np.empty(3 * nverts)
        me.vertices.foreach_get("co", vcoords)
        edges = np.zeros(2 * nedges, dtype=np.int32)
        me.edges.foreach_get("vertices", edges)

        vcoords3d = vcoords.reshape((-1, 3))
        a, b = edges.reshape((-1, 2)).T

        edge_lengths = np.linalg.norm(
                vcoords3d[a] - vcoords3d[b],
                axis=1,
                )
        self.edges = edges.reshape((-1, 2))
        self.vcoords3d = vcoords3d
        self.edge_lengths = edge_lengths
        
        # colors
        
        col = me.vertex_colors.get(vcol)
        self.vcol_layer = BATVertColors(me, col.data) if col else None

# give it a test run

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
                
ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data

mesh0 = BATMesh(me)

# warped object copy
copy = scene.objects.get("Copy")
assert(copy) # <--- 
mesh1 = BATMesh(copy.data)
nverts = len(copy.data.vertices)
delta_edge_length = (mesh1.edge_lengths - mesh0.edge_lengths) / mesh0.edge_lengths
rgbas = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1]] * nverts)
# could be a more numpy-centric way to do please share
for i in range(nverts):
    link_edges = mesh0.vert_link_edges(i)
    m = np.mean(delta_edge_length[link_edges])
    if m > 0:
        rgbas[i] = (1, 0, 0, 1)

mesh1.vcol_layer.color_by_verts(rgbas)
```

**Some notes.**

Have reduced  to no `bmesh` and "`for x in y`"  looping over the vertices once. Looping is generally the rate determining step.  Using methods as displayed above is going to be a lot quicker.

**Some minor tweaks to speed up question code.**

*Since it's there, and it works, it's worth making a few comments re possible ways to optimize too*

The default cube has 8 verts and 24 loops. In question code each vert is being processed for each connected face (loop), or 3 times.  A default dictionary could be used here, or another way to keep tabs not to process a vert more than once. (*Example of a vert index to loop index LUT*)

```
>>> from collections import default_dict

>>> lut = defaultdict(list)
>>> for f in bm.faces:
...     for l in f.loops:
...         lut[l.vert.index].append(l.index)
...         
>>> pprint.pprint(lut)
defaultdict(<class 'list'>,
            {0: [0, 15, 19],
             1: [1, 14, 22],
             2: [3, 4, 16],
             3: [2, 5, 21],
             4: [11, 12, 18],
             5: [10, 13, 23],
             6: [7, 8, 17],
             7: [6, 9, 20]})
```

In this case tho would loop verts, and set color for each then when looping faceloops

```
loop[layer] = colors[loop.vert.index]
```

Bmesh has worked out all the links for us

This is going to be very expensive (re above) each time looping over all edges to find a vert's linked edges,

```
# get all the edges that belong to this vertex
Eges = [e.index for e in bm.edges if v in e.verts]
```

and can be replaced with `v.link_edges` *eg for cube*

```
>>> for v in bm.verts:
...     [e.index for e in v.link_edges]
...     
[0, 1, 10]
[1, 2, 11]
[0, 3, 4]
[2, 3, 5]
[7, 9, 10]
[8, 9, 11]
[4, 6, 7]
[5, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Thank you for your awesome response, it is way more then I expected! 
* more numpy centric way : for "rgbas = np.array([[0, 0, 0, 1]] * nverts)"                                 
* can be changed to rgbas = np.zeros(np.shape(nverts))

Comment: Cheers and NP coding up some "BAT" stuff and gave a chance to test it out  Intriguing choice to use mean edge lengths over vert co moving.  also curious re `colormap_jet(avg)`.  Ok re edit  yeah that looks better.. (in hindsight `np.ones` prob matches default better)